# Visual Studio - Android - "The emulator exited unexpectedly. Please check the emulator settings"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am just starting out with mobile app development and I have an issue when trying to run the emulator for a "HelloWorld" application that builds correctly.

I am on OSX using Visual Studio Community, and as soon as I try to run the app it says:

> "The emulator exited unexpectedly. Please check the emulator settings"

I have installed the Android SDK and NDK with homebrew and configured them in VS like so:

[image: Android Configuration]

I have also installed these platforms:

[image]

I am very new to all of this.

Comment: This keep happening to me after recent updates. Wasn't happening before

Comment: I am facing the same issues while running the app over Mac-Visual Studio, any solution for this?

Comment: Please post your emulator settings.

Comment: Anyone resolved this? encountering this now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem after updating BigSur from 11.2 to 11.3 a couple of weeks ago.
This worked for me on VS for Mac 2019 :

1. On VS for Mac, go to Tools > SDK Manager (see first picture).
   [image]

This will open up the Preferences at the right place.

2. In the second picture, uncheck "Android Emulator" and click "Apply".
   [image]
3. It should be automatic from now on.
   For me, it said that my SDK needed repair, so I clicked Repair and it redownloaded everything it needed.
4. Restart VS and next time it should run the emulator.